# Android Gradle: Install all build types on one device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, android-build-type, android-variants

How do I configure my project to be able to install the debug version alongside the release version when using GCM, ContentProvider, AccountType? (without the use of flavors)

I keep getting errors such as: [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16267987/1228221) or [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043933/1228221)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing a debug apk and the release apk on the same device is tricky if you are only using build types and not flavors ([Why Build types and not flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908019/1228221))

Most blog post are either outdated (talking about packageName) or [force you to use flavors](https://blog.grandcentrix.net/how-to-install-different-app-variants-on-one-android-device/) because the solution they propose does not support `applicationIdSuffix` and a `build type` cannot declare `applicationId` therefore you need to use a `flavors`

The solution I propose uses

- an authority per build type
- an account type per build type
- a GCM permission per build type

For this to work I use `applicationIdSuffix`, [manifest placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support), `BuildConfigField` and `resValue` in the Gradle file.

The only problem left is when you want to have a different name for app and per language the string is not set as translatable ([bug aosp tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152198))
This forces you to set `abortOnError false` otherwise you won't be able to make a release build.

**build.gradle**

```
project.ext {
    defaultApplicationId = "com.myapp.package"
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId defaultApplicationId

        manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationIdWithSuffix: "${applicationId}" ]

        buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"${applicationId}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\"${applicationId}.provider\""

        resValue "string", "account_type", "${applicationId}"
        resValue "string", "authority", "${applicationId}.provider"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true

            manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationIdWithSuffix: defaultApplicationId + ".debug" ]

            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE",  "\"${defaultApplicationId}.debug\""
            buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\"${defaultApplicationId}.debug.provider\""

            resValue "string", "account_type", "${defaultApplicationId}.debug"
            resValue "string", "authority", "${defaultApplicationId}.debug.provider"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage" >

    <permission
        android:name="${applicationIdWithSuffix}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationIdWithSuffix}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <provider
            android:name=".MyContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationIdWithSuffix}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Sync adapter xml**

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/authority"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"/>
```

**Account authenticator**

```
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/account_type"
    .../>
```

**ContentProvider**

I have a constant for Authority which takes it from the BuildConfig.

```
AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.AUTHORITY
```

**Account type**

To get the account type you take it from the BuildConfig too.

```
BuildConfig.ACCOUNT_TYPE
```

**Multi language app name**

If you want different names per app & language:

**debug/values-en/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp debug EN</string>
</resources>
```

**debug/values-fr/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp debug FR</string>
</resources>
```

**main/values-en/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp EN</string>
</resources>
```

**main/values-fr/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp FR</string>
</resources>
```