# How can I pass switches to my Android app to control its behavior during development?

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native

While developing a certain portion of my React Native app, it would be easier for me if the app just displayed mock data rather than actually calling through to the API server as it would in production. I want to configure the app somehow to control whether it has this behavior when I debug it. In a console application, I would normally add a command-line switch, say `--load-mock-data` that would communicate this to the app. However, Android apps do not accept command-line arguments: see [Android native application command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197242/android-native-application-command-line-arguments). So how would I control this behavior in an Android app from my terminal?

Comment: For Android you can try a library like this: https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock (I don't know if this works for Reactive Native too), maybe you can use something Javascript related like [this](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) or [this](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dagger 2, you could represent your server as an interface, and the `@Module` that `@Provides` it could provide the real one or a mock one depending on the value of `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.